# lightbox image pushed to the right side if I add with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

The Problem appears on the [following page](http://knuever-recycling.de/containerdienst_pk.php). if you click on an Image the lightbox appears but the image is out of the border.....how could I fix this?

thanks!

Comment: It looks like the use of the `container` class on one of the lightbox divs is inheriting a different width value, which the image is trying to fill.

Comment: could you please give me a direct hint how to fix that issue?I am kind of new to these things

Comment: nevermind, I just renamed all "container" in my style.css to containerz and now everything works. thanks for the hint thou :)

Comment: Bootstrap also has a class named container that was applying certain styles, so it was conflicting with what you were trying to do with that class. Renaming your class worked because now it is no longer inheriting the bootstrap styles too. Good luck!